# Spring 2.5 MVC :Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: The url cannot be null

Tags: spring, netbeans, glassfish

I am trying a Spring MVC 2.5 program that uses JDBCTemplate helper class to insert a record into a Derby table. I am using Netbeans IDE 6.5.1 and using GlassFish Server.

But I get this exception:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection;
   nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: The url cannot be null.
```

I have ensured the below already:

- Have added the Derby.jar, DerbyClient.jar into the "libraries" folder of the Web Application.
- Tried a Java Application that uses Spring JDBCTemplate to insert a record into a Derby table using DerbyClient.jar and this program works beautifully.

I have also tried few other suggestions found on this site like:

- Added the DerbyClient.jar and Derby.jar into the lib folder of Glassfish.
- Ensured that these jar files are available in the classpath.

Can you please tell me where I might be wrong ?

My properties file: datasrc.properties

```
driverClassName=org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
url=jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample
username=APP
password=APP
```

My **dataSource** bean entry :

```
<bean name="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${password}"/>
</bean>
```

My Class called MyDAO has a property called **dataSource** which will be injected with the **dataSource** bean like below:

```
<bean id="mydao" class="MyDAO">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

Full stack trace:

```
    SEVERE: ApplicationDispatcher[/SpringMVCIceCream2] PWC1231: Servlet.service() for servlet    dispatcher threw exception
java.sql.SQLException: The url cannot be null
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:554)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:154)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:283)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:271)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:255)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:236)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:113)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:357)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:404)
        at MyDAO.create(MyDAO.java:66)
        at IcecreamController1.onSubmit(IcecreamController1.java:30)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleFormController.onSubmit(SimpleFormController.java:409)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleFormController.onSubmit(SimpleFormController.java:381)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleFormController.processFormSubmission(SimpleFormController.java:267)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractFormController.handleRequestInternal(AbstractFormController.java:265)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:874)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:808)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:476)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:441)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.servletService(ApplicationFilterChain.java:431)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:885)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:732)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:554)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:485)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:377)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:783)
        at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java from :53)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:109)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:403)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:366)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.servletService(ApplicationFilterChain.java:431)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.preInvoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:462)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:186)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:719)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:657)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:96)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:187)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:719)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:657)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:651)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1030)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:719)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:657)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:651)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1030)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:325)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:242)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:180)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(DefaultProcessorTask.java:633)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProcessorTask.doProcess(DefaultProcessorTask.java:570)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProcessorTask.process(DefaultProcessorTask.java:827)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:152)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GlassfishProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(GlassfishProtocolChain.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:103)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:89)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:67)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:56)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.WorkerThreadImpl.processTask(WorkerThreadImpl.java:325)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.WorkerThreadImpl.run(WorkerThreadImpl.java:184)
SEVERE: StandardWrapperValve[jsp]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.sql.SQLException: The url cannot be null
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:554)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:154)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:283)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:271)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:255)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:236)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:113)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:357)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:404)
        at MyDAO.create(MyDAO.java:66)
        at IcecreamController1.onSubmit(IcecreamController1.java:30)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleFormController.onSubmit(SimpleFormController.java:409)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleFormController.onSubmit(SimpleFormController.java:381)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleFormController.processFormSubmission(SimpleFormController.java:267)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractFormController.handleRequestInternal(AbstractFormController.java:265)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:874)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:808)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:476)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:441)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.servletService(ApplicationFilterChain.java:431)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:885)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:732)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:554)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:485)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:377)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:783)
        at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java from :53)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:109)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:403)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:366)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.servletService(ApplicationFilterChain.java:431)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.preInvoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:462)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:186)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:719)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:657)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:96)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:187)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:719)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:657)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:651)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1030)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:719)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:657)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:651)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1030)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:325)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:242)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:180)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(DefaultProcessorTask.java:633)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProcessorTask.doProcess(DefaultProcessorTask.java:570)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProcessorTask.process(DefaultProcessorTask.java:827)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:152)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GlassfishProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(GlassfishProtocolChain.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:103)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:89)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:67)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:56)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.WorkerThreadImpl.processTask(WorkerThreadImpl.java:325)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.WorkerThreadImpl.run(WorkerThreadImpl.java:184)
```

Comment: Try to read some of your properties into other bean, you will know if it is DriverManagerDataSource problem or simply your properties are unreachable and therefore url stays null, in younger Spring versions it would throw an exception but you are dealing with 2.5 so you never know

Comment: Did you try to set the URL in your dataSource bean entry?

Comment: The dataSource bean once its injected into the MyDAO bean, using the println statement I am printing the values of dataSource , all the values of driverName, url , username and password are printing correctly. In MyDAO, in the setter method of dataSource, I am further initializing JDBCTemplate object with this dataSource. I am also printing the JDBCTemplate object and its contents. It seems to have the dataSource details: